# Debugger for OpenCL

Tags: opencl

I am working on OpenCL. Does anyone know of a good debugger for OpenCL so that I can step into the OpenCL code and trace?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Perhaps Gremedy's OpenCL debugger would be helpful?
http://www.gremedy.com/gDEBuggerCL.php

Comment: Now it is available in AMD website updated version 6.2  available for both Windows & Linux  http://developer.amd.com/tools/gDEBugger/Pages/default.aspx

Comment: @ocluser That's no longer current. AMD has abandoned gDEBugger, which is superseded by [CodeXL](http://developer.amd.com/tools/heterogeneous-computing/codexl/). [Gremedy's](http://www.gremedy.com/gDEBuggerCL.php) is the latest version of gDEBugger (Dec 11 2012).

Answer (score 18):

You may also want to look into CodeXL:

https://gpuopen.com/compute-product/codexl/

CodeXL was originally developed by AMD, but was later released as an open-source project.

Comment: CodeXL is indeed a great OpenCL debugger, it was formerly known as gDebugger

Comment: I consider CodeXL to be by far the best freely available opencl tool out there. It gives you CPU/GPU Debugging and profiling all in one.

Comment: looks pretty abandoned recently

Answer (score 9):

your best bet is Intel Debugger for CPU, announced at Intel OpenCL SDK 1.5:

[Intel OpenCL SDK](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-sdk/)
you can step-by-step debug in visual studio.

[Visual Studio debugger plug-in](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2011/09/26/increase-opencl-application-performance-with-the-new-intel-opencl-sdk-15/)

Comment: Will the Intel SDK work on AMD CPU?

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you can try to use GDB on x86 CPU under Linux OS, see AMD's tutorial:
http://developer.amd.com/gpu/ATIStreamSDK/assets/Debugging_OpenCL_with_GDB_on_x86_CPUs.pdf

Comment: The above link is broken as of 2022 :(

Answer (score 6):

Only AMD gDEBugger supports OpenCL step by step running and other tasty features
http://developer.amd.com/tools/gDEBugger/Pages/default.aspx

NVidia Parallel NSight and other NVidia products will not support OpenCL debugging due to marketing decisions.

Comment: AMD has abandoned gDEBugger, which is superseded by [CodeXL](http://developer.amd.com/tools/heterogeneous-computing/codexl/). [Gremedy's](http://www.gremedy.com/gDEBuggerCL.php) is the latest version of gDEBugger (Dec 11 2012).

Answer (score 6):

I generally recommend using [GPUVerify](http://multicore.doc.ic.ac.uk/tools/GPUVerify/) from Imperial College London and [Oclgrind](https://github.com/jrprice/Oclgrind/wiki) from the University of Bristol, especially when you are stuck debugging your OpenCL programs (but better even before that).

Comment: Heh!  I came here to mention oclgrind, but you beat me to it :-)  But it doesnt support warps for now I think?  Does GPUVerify provide step-by-step debugging of opencl kernels?

Answer (score 3):

NVIDIA's [Parallel Nsight](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/nexus.html) debugger (formerly known as Nexus) supports OpenCL (GPU).

From the website:

> Parallel Nsight supports CUDA C, OpenCL, DirectCompute, Direct3D, and OpenGL.

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: @MiroKrsjak Parallel Nsight was renamed to Nsight Visual Studio Edition and does support OpenCL (c.f. https://www.developer.nvidia.com/nsight-visual-studio-edition). The other Nsight tools do not.

Answer (score 3):

I have not used it, but [CLBuilder](http://web.me.com/cducommun/CLBuilder/Home.html) looks promising

> Main features of CLBuilder
>
> 1. Write OpenCL kernels with color syntaxing
> 2. Compile the kernel to check errors without the need to launch and
>      debug your own app.
> 3. Easily create and select Build settings.
> 4. Define kernel input values and check results.
> 5. Profile the kernel execution time in order to improve performances.
> 6. Create different Work Item Sizes Set (Global and Local) to check
>      performances.
> 7. Execute the kernel with printf on CPU and easily debug the code.
> 8. Display input and output values on a chart.
> 9. Consult execution log in order to see what CLBuilder is doing (log
>      each OpenCL C function).
> 10. Check Local and Constant arguments and resources used by the
>       kernel.
> 11. Generate C code to execute the kernel, CLBuilder will also compile
>       this generated source code and execute it.
> 12. Easily check all OpenCL properties including platform information.

Comment: Note: CLBuilder seems to be a comercial product for Mac.

Comment: @EmanuelEy Yep, it costs 25USD'ish